# What is the difference between SEC Form S-1 and S-3 filings?

Tags: sec, electronic-filing

I've been digging into S-1 and S-3 filings and I can get the general idea behind them both but am unsure about the specific distinctions between the two types of filings. Does anyone know what these distinctions are? I've been researching it but haven't been able to locate the solution to this.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/s-3.asp

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think S-1 is for IPOs, and S-3 is for subsequent share offerings (under some specific conditions only).

Comment: @Flux I thought that was the case but some companies have multiple S-1 even after IPO which made me question that: https://www.bamsec.com/companies/1675634/shiftpixy-inc

Comment: S-3 is a simplified S-1 that companies can use if they fulfill some conditions.